# Horizontal stacked bar charts stratified by treatment

Tags: r, ggplot2

Any idea how I can produce a plot like this for a study with 8 ordinal outcome categories stratified by treatment with separate stacked bar graphs? I guess I could do it in ggplot2, but the dotted lines indicating the different categories baffles me and I guess there is a package for this, but so far I havent found it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there might be a package, you could actually achieve this quite easily using vanilla `ggplot2`. The only more "advanced" step is the use of `stage` to nudge the starting/end positions for the lines.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = factor(am), fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", width = .6) +
  geom_line(
    aes(
      group = cyl,
      y = stage(factor(am), after_stat = y + ifelse(y == 1, +.3, -.3))
    ),
    stat = "count", position = "fill",
    linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_number(scale = 100),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]